# How do I render boolean values as checkboxes from MS Access in Jtable?

Tags: java, microsoft-access-2003, netbeans-7.3

I have a Field name in my database which, if inserted from JForms, is simply "Active" or "Inactive". It doesn't use the True/False data type.

All I want is for that field to display as checkboxes inside the Jtable.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want it, as you said, to *display*, (and not be up-datable, i.e. a control), then have you tried dragging a check box onto your form, setting the *Data | Control Source* property to something like this?

```
=([your field]='Active')
```

This should return a Boolean value to the check box and make the check box display the state of Active or not.

BTW, you might also want to make the check box not up-datable by setting Data | Enabled to No.

If you really must have it also be a control, that is much harder I think and would involve an event updating the underlying table.